# aws cli command not working when installed local folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I installed the [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html) program as mentioned in this doc without sudo to local folder. But when I try to run the command line utility I get error.

```
$ ./aws/install -i awscli-app -b awscli-bin
$ ls awscli-bin/
 aws  aws_completer
$ ls -alh awscli-bin
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x  2 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 prod prod   29 Jun 22 14:14 aws -> awscli-app/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx  1 prod prod   39 Jun 22 14:14 aws_completer -> awscli-app/v2/current/bin/aws_completer
$ ./awscli-bin/aws --version
-bash: ./awscli-bin/aws: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here, can anyone help me ?

**EDIT**

```
$ ls -alh awscli-app/v2/current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 prod prod 20 Jun 22 14:14 awscli-app/v2/current -> awscli-app/v2/2.0.24
$ ls -alh  awscli-app/v2/2.0.24
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x  4 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 bin
drwxr-xr-x 11 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 dist
```

**EDIT2**

```
$ ./awscli-app/v2/2.0.24/bin/aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.24 Python/3.7.3 Linux/3.13.0-63-generic botocore/2.0.0dev28
$ ls -alh awscli-app/v2/2.0.24/bin
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 prod prod 4.0K Jun 22 14:14 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 prod prod   11 Jun 22 14:14 aws -> ../dist/aws
lrwxrwxrwx 1 prod prod   21 Jun 22 14:14 aws_completer -> ../dist/aws_completer
```

Comment: Does awscli-app/v2/current/bin/aws exist?

Comment: @mrblewog It is a symlink, please check my edit.

Comment: Yup, so a) can you `ls -alh awscli-app/v2/2.0.24/bin`, and b) does `./awscli-app/v2/2.0.24/bin/aws --version` work?

Comment: @mrblewog B -> Works. See edit for A.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Using relative paths instead of a full paths seemed to be root cause (didn't look at the installer to determine why):

relative paths attempts:

```
$ ./aws/install --bin-dir aws-bin --install-dir aws-cli
$ ls -al aws-bin
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:05 .
drwxrwxrwx 20 root  root  4096 Oct 26 02:05 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 luser luser   26 Oct 26 02:05 aws -> aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx  1 luser luser   36 Oct 26 02:05 aws_completer -> aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws_completer
$ ls -al aws-cli/v2/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:05 2.8.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 luser luser   16 Oct 26 02:05 current -> aws-cli/v2/2.8.5
```

```
$ ./aws/install --bin-dir ./aws-bin --install-dir ./aws-cli
lrwxrwxrwx  1 luser luser   26 Oct 26 02:07 aws -> ./aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
<...>
```

absolute paths:

```
$ CURRENT_DIR=$( pwd )
$ ./aws/install --bin-dir ${CURRENT_DIR}/aws-bin --install-dir ${CURRENT_DIR}/aws-cli
$ ls -al aws-bin
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  2 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:14 .
drwxrwxrwx 20 root  root  4096 Oct 26 02:14 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 luser luser   77 Oct 26 02:14 aws -> ${CURRENT_DIR}/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws
lrwxrwxrwx  1 luser luser   87 Oct 26 02:14 aws_completer -> ${CURRENT_DIR}/aws-cli/v2/current/bin/aws_completer
$ ls -al aws-cli/v2/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 luser luser 4096 Oct 26 02:14 2.8.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 luser luser   67 Oct 26 02:14 current -> ${CURRENT_DIR}/aws-cli/v2/2.8.5
```

Using relative paths makes relative sym links, and that's a no-go. Hopefully this helps someone in future years :)